# Fail to try webhook for Microsoft Teams site

Tags: microsoft-teams, asp.net-webhooks

anybody know if I do something wrong or if something is not working at the moment?

- I use [MessageCard Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) and want to send data to a Teams-Channel.
- I did setup the connector and got a webhook url.
  [image]
- Now I want to send some samples to the channel (valid json)

Getting this error:
[image]

Any idea what I do wrong?

**Update**

Sample JSON

```
{
  "@type": "MessageCard",
  "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
  "summary": "Issue 4711",
  "themeColor": "0078D7",
  "title": "Issue opened: \"TEST Message for webhook\"",
  "sections": [
    {
      "activityTitle": "Yves Rausch",
      "activitySubtitle": "10/12/2017, 22:34",
      "facts": [
        {
          "name": "Title:",
          "value": "TinyMCE 4 implementieren"
        },
        {
          "name": "Issue #:",
          "value": "6417"
        }
      ],
      "text": "There is a push webhook info and leads me to the workflow."
    }
  ],
  "potentialAction": [
    {
      "@type": "OpenUri",
      "name": "View in process",
      "targets": [
        { "os": "default", "uri": "https://intranet.tqsoft.net/ror/workflowact/6417" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you add some sample code and the JSON payload?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft added some Json example, but any Sample from the page, e.g. Microsoft Flow approval, results in the same Error 400.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft When I check *Params* in the request, it is empty, regardless the json code I have.

Comment: How are you sending this payload to the webhook?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier for the start I use https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/ for testing and want later user C#.Net

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry, I misunderstood that you were _sending_ in through the playground as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in MessageCard Playground at the moment which is preventing it from POSTing to the webhook endpoint properly.

I suggest trying Postman for issuing the HTTP request. You can simply copy and past the JSON from the playground. See [Sending actionable messages via Office 365 Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/actionable-messages-via-connectors#sending-actionable-messages-via-office-365-connectors) for details on how to set this up.